# How to overload the 'new' method?

Tags: struct, overloading, rust

I'm just started to learn Rust and I'm wondering if there is way to overload methods.
At first I created a struct and used a 'impl' to implement basic 'new' method. Then I thought to add 'new' method with some params, and I tried to use trait for that.

The following code was successfully compiled but once I tried to use 'new' with params, compiler gave me an error about extra params.
So how should I overload methods in Rust?

```
pub struct Words<'a> {
    pub nouns: Vec<&'a str>,
}

trait Test<'a>{
    fn new(nouns: Vec<&'a str>) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> Words<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Words<'a>{
        let nouns = vec!["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
        Words{ nouns: nouns }
    }

    pub fn print(&self){
        for i in self.nouns.iter(){
            print!("{} ", i);
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> for Words<'a> {
    fn new(nouns: Vec<&'a str>) -> Words<'a>{
        Words{ nouns: nouns }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust indeed has overloading via traits, but you can't change the number of parameters, and their types can only be changed if they were declared as generic on the first place in the trait definition.

In cases like yours, it's common to have a method like `new_with_nouns` to specialize what you mean:

```
impl<'a> Words<'a> {
    fn new() -> Words { /* ... */ }
    fn new_with_nouns(nouns: Vec<&'a str>) -> Words<'a> { /* ... */ }
}
```

For more complex data structures, where the `new_with_something` pattern would lead to a combinatorial explosion, the builder pattern is common (here I'll assume that `Words` has a `separator` field, just to demonstrate):

```
struct WordsBuilder<'a> {
    separator: Option<&'a str>,
    nouns: Option<Vec<&'a str>>,
}

impl<'a> WordsBuilder<'a> {
    fn new() -> WordsBuilder<'a> {
        WordsBuilder { separator: None, nouns: None }
    }

    fn nouns(mut self, nouns: Vec<&'a str>) -> WordsBuilder<'a> {
        self.nouns = Some(nouns);
        self
    }

    fn separator(mut self, separator: &'a str) -> WordsBuilder<'a> {
        self.separator = Some(separator);
        self
    }

    fn build(self) -> Words<'a> {
        Words {
            separator: self.separator.unwrap_or(","),
            nouns:     self.nouns.unwrap_or_else(|| {
                vec!["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to how the [stdlib's `thread::Builder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html) works, for example.