# How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?

Tags: rust, convention, builder-pattern

Based on the following examples, its possible to write a build-pattern with chained method calls in Rust which either passes by value or by reference (with a lifetime specifier)

- [Is it possible to create a macro to implement builder pattern methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158167)
- [How to overload the 'new' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28000113/432509) (top answer)
- https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/builder.md

A builder pattern in Rust may look something like this:

```
 ui::Button::new()
    .label("Test")
    .align(Align::Center)
    .build();
```

When writing idiomatic Rust is there a strong preference for one over another?

Is there some good example of how to write this in Rust?

Comment: While I'm not a fan of the builder pattern, I'd just follow the simple approach from the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern). It's pretty idiomatic.

Comment: Also not *especially* a fan, coming Python code that used keyword style, eg:  `ui.button(label="Test", align='CENTER')` style, so looking for something similar in Rust.

Comment: @ideasman42: Rust has `Button { label = "Test", align = "CENTER", .. Default::default() }` syntax :)

Comment: Yes, I strongly considered using this style of syntax... (will ask another question on this infact), btw, wouldn't it be:  `Button { label: "Test", ....` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629819

Answer (score 8):

There are actually *two* trade-offs:

- should the named setter accept `self` by value or reference?
- should the final `build` method accept `self` by value or reference?

My recommendation is:

- mutable reference for the setters
- value for the `build` method

This differs slightly from the [Builder Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern) presented in the Rust Book which uses a reference in `build`.

---

*Why passing by mutable reference for the setters?*

While a compiler *may* optimize away the moves caused by a call to `fn label(self, &str) -> ButtonBuilder`, it is not guaranteed.

On the other hand, the mutable reference way is already optimal so that you need not rely on the optimizer.

---

*Why passing by value for the final `build`?*

For builders only composed of `Copy` fields, there is no difference between `build` taking `self` or `&self`.

However, as soon as the builder contains non-`Copy` fields, passing `&self` to `build` requires deep-cloning these fields.

On the other hand, passing `self` by value allows `build` to move the fields, which avoid unnecessary copies.

If one wishes to re-use the builder, then the builder should implement `Clone`.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the builder pattern mostly implemented by taking ownership of the Builder when modifying it, and by reference for `build()`. For example,

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Foo {
    value: usize,
}

struct FooBuilder {
    foos: usize,
    bars: usize,
}

impl FooBuilder {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder {
            foos: 0,
            bars: 0,
        }
    }
    fn set_foos(mut self, foos: usize) -> FooBuilder {
        self.foos = foos;
        self
    }
    fn set_bars(mut self, bars: usize) -> FooBuilder {
        self.bars = bars;
        self
    }
    fn build(&self) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            value: self.foos + self.bars,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooBuilder::new()
        .set_foos(2)
        .set_bars(3)
        .build();
    assert_eq!(foo, Foo { value: 5 });
}
```

[Try on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23[derive(Debug%2C%20Eq%2C%20PartialEq)]struct%20Foo%20%7B%20%20%20%20value%3A%20usize%2C%7Dstruct%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20foos%3A%20usize%2C%20%20%20%20bars%3A%20usize%2C%7Dimpl%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20fn%20new()%20->%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foos%3A%200%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bars%3A%200%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20fn%20set_foos(mut%20self%2C%20foos%3A%20usize)%20->%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.foos%20%3D%20foos%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20fn%20set_bars(mut%20self%2C%20bars%3A%20usize)%20->%20FooBuilder%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.bars%20%3D%20bars%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20fn%20build(%26self)%20->%20Foo%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20self.foos%20%2B%20self.bars%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%7Dfn%20main()%20%7B%20%20%20%20let%20foo%20%3D%20FooBuilder%3A%3Anew()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.set_foos(2)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.set_bars(3)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.build()%3B%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(foo%2C%20Foo%20%7B%20value%3A%205%20%7D)%3B%7D&version=stable&backtrace=2)

This makes chaining simple, while allowing reuse of the builder.

Comment: The book, instead, uses a mutable reference to pass the builder (no lifetime), see [Builder Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern). I expect this is for efficiency.

Comment: Ah, and interestingly... I *also* disagree (with both the book and you) on passing `&self` to `build`. Put a `String` in `FooBuilder`, and you'll be forced to `clone` it in `build`, even if nobody which to reuse the instance of the builder... that's clearly wasteful.