# Should I take `self` by value or mutable reference when using the Builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, ownership

So far, I've seen two builder patterns in official Rust code and other crates:

```rust
impl DataBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> DataBuilder { ... }
    pub fn arg1(&mut self, arg1: Arg1Type) -> &mut Builder { ... }
    pub fn arg2(&mut self, arg2: Arg2Type) -> &mut Builder { ... }
    ...
    pub fn build(&self) -> Data { ... }
}
```

```rust
impl DataBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> DataBuilder { ... }
    pub fn arg1(self, arg1: Arg1Type) -> Builder { ... }
    pub fn arg2(self, arg2: Arg2Type) -> Builder { ... }
    ...
    pub fn build(self) -> Data { ... }
}
```

I'm writing a new crate and I'm a bit confused which pattern I should choose. I know it will be painful if I change some APIs later, so I want to make the decision now.

I understand the semantic difference between them, but which one should we prefer in practical situations? Or how should we choose between them? Why?

Comment: FWIW, the `derive_builder` crate lays out some pros and cons: https://docs.rs/derive_builder/latest/derive_builder/#builder-patterns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Is it beneficial to build multiple values from the same builder?*

- If yes, use `&mut self`
- If no, use `self`

---

Consider [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html) which is a builder for [`std::thread::Thread`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html). It uses `Option` fields internally to configure how to build the thread:

```
pub struct Builder {
    name: Option<String>,
    stack_size: Option<usize>,
}
```

It uses `self` to `.spawn()` the thread because it needs ownership of the `name`. It could theoretically use `&mut self` and `.take()` the name out of the field, but then subsequent calls to `.spawn()` wouldn't create identical results, which is kinda bad design. It could choose to `.clone()` the name, but then there's an additional and often unneeded cost to spawn a thread. Using `&mut self` would be a detriment.

Consider [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) which serves as a builder for a [`std::process::Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html). It has fields containing the program, args, environment, and pipe configuration:

```
pub struct Command {
    program: CString,
    args: Vec<CString>,
    env: CommandEnv,
    stdin: Option<Stdio>,
    stdout: Option<Stdio>,
    stderr: Option<Stdio>,
    // ...
}
```

It uses `&mut self` to `.spawn()` because it does *not* take ownership of these fields to create the `Child`. It has to internally copy all that data over to the OS anyway, so there's no reason to consume `self`. There's also a tangible benefit and use-case to spawning multiple child processes with the same configuration.

Consider [`std::fs::OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) which serves as a builder for [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html). It only stores basic configuration:

```
pub struct OpenOptions {
    read: bool,
    write: bool,
    append: bool,
    truncate: bool,
    create: bool,
    create_new: bool,
    // ...
}
```

It uses `&mut self` to `.open()` because it does not need ownership of anything to work. It is somewhat similar to the thread builder since there is a path associated with a file just as there is a name associated with a thread, however, the file path is only passed in to `.open()` and not stored along with the builder. There's a use-case for opening multiple files with the same configuration.

---

The considerations above really only cover the semantics of `self` in the `.build()` method, but there's plenty of justification that if you pick one method you should use that for the interim methods as well:

- API consistency
- chaining `(&mut self) -> &mut Self` into `build(self)` obviously wouldn't compile
- using `(self) -> Self` into `build(&mut self)` would limit the flexibility of the builder to be reused long-term

See also: [How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617182)