# Chainable method efficiency (builder pattern)

Tags: rust, builder

I wonder how memory efficient the builder pattern actually is for big scenarios. I'm thinking about an event sourcing architecture context with the potential of many events for an aggregate.
Anyway, so the pattern I mean would be something like this in an abstract manner. Just assume it would be useful.

```
pub struct MyStruct {
   pub values: Vec<String>,
}

trait MyStruct {
  pub fn builder() -> MyStructBuilder {
    MyStructBuilder::default()
  }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyStructBuilder {
  values: Vec<String>,
}

impl MyStructBuilder {
  pub fn value(mut self, entry: &str) -> Self {
    self.values.push(entry.to_string());
    self
  }
  
  pub fn build(self) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { values: self.values }
  }
}
```

If I would now do something like this:

```
MyStruct::builder()
  .value("a")
  .value("b")
  .value("c")
  // ... many ...
  .value("z")
  .build()
```

How bad is this actually for the memory. In thereby I actually don't mean the vector thingy (that's just from the stupid example). Assume a proper struct with multiple fields, option values, also vectors yes, etc. But how bad is it basically that the builder always "re-creates" itself again and again and again. Does the compiler optimizes it so that it basically doesn't matter. Because it sees that any instance after a `value()` call is nether re-used except for the very next chain call?

Thank you very much for any help to understand what would actually happen under the hood here.

Comment: The compiler should optimize it away, it has all information necessary.

Comment: Matthieu M. talks about efficiency a little in [their answer to "How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41617772/442760)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617182/how-to-write-an-idiomatic-build-pattern-with-chained-method-calls-in-rust)

Comment: @V0ldek I think this aligns with the former link. Unfortunately using a mutable reference has disadvantages which do not work in my case. But it helped to understand it better.